# How to duplicate table with constraint and key information in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to duplicate a table in SQL Server:

```
select * 
into student_info 
from student_constraint 
where 1 = 2;
```

But it only duplicates the schema.

How can I duplicate the table with constraint and key information?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, you can script out the table with the full creation statements.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want schema only, you can use the generate script option provided in SSMS.

> To generate schema script, right click on the source table and click
>   Script Table as -> Create To, and choose the location for the output.

If you want Data with Schema, In SSMS you have option to generate data with schema,  or only schema , you can try the following approach.

> To generate SQL scripts for one or more tables along with their data,
>   right click on the database and click on Tasks->Generate Scripts.
>   Choose the object that you want to backup and click on Next. On the
>   next dialog window, choose the location for your script, and then
>   click on Advanced.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to copy Table and Data from source table to destination table
**select * into student_info from student_constraint;**

and now add new command to add constraints to specific columns

**ALTER TABLE student_info
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Student_info  PRIMARY KEY (ID);**